# How to add SDK module in Android project

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am trying to implement a payment processor in my Android app that works in the Middle East, which is an SDK module, but not having much success. Their customer support has not been helpful so far.

These are the steps they provide. However in step 1, I'm not sure where to clone it, in the libs dir? Then in step 2 it's not clear what to make of this? Should I write `include :library', ':app'` - or perhaps `include ':goSellSDK-Android', ':app'`. In step 3, their Module simply does not show up in the list, no matter what I try for step 2.

If I try to add the module through 'import module from source' it adds the sample, not the library. I feel I am missing something, any help is appreciated.

> step 1 - Clone goSellSDK library from Tap repository
> git@github.com:Tap-Payments/goSellSDK-Android.git

> step 2 - Add goSellSDK library to your project settings.gradle file as following
> include ':library', ':YourAppName'

> step 3 - Setup your project to include goSellSDK as a dependency Module.
>
> - File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> << your project name >>
> - Dependencies -> click on + icon in the screen bottom -> add Module
> - Dependency select goSellSDK library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow the [installation guide using jitpack](https://github.com/Tap-Payments/goSellSDK-Android#installation_with_jitpack)

1. Add JitPack in your root `build.gradle` at the end of repositories:

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           ...
           maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add dependency to your module's `build.gradle` file (propably your app module)

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.github.Tap-Payments:goSellSDK-Android:2.12.1'
   }
   ```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: I didn't mention that part but I did that already. However the previous step is supposed to be done first, but it doesn't make the module appear, and none of the implementation works. When I add "import company.tap.gosellapi.GoSellSDK;" and put "GoSellSDK.init(..)" in my main activity, it tells me 'cannot resolve symbol init'.

Comment: Ok I added the init to the launcher activity and now recognizes it!

Comment: Great to hear! I believe those are options, not steps, you should just choose one. Could you mark my answer as accepted if this has helped you?